# Pandas - Replace a string by another column value on condition

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have a dataframe `transactions` with 2 columns `source_number`and `return_code`

I would like to keep the string values of `source number` whenever the `return code` is not "successfully completed" and replace it with the string of numbers from `return code` whenever it is successfully completed.

I came up with this:

`if "Successfully completed" in transactions['return_code']:
    transactions['source_number'] = transactions['return_code'] 
else:
    transactions['source_number']`

to then remove "|Successfully completed" from the new value in `source number` but this does not make any modification when I run the script.

Any help is more than welcomed! Thank you

[dataframe_pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfKYW.png)

Comment: Can we assume you loaded your data as a `dataframe` with the `pandas` module?

Comment: I also tried this without success:

`transactions.loc[transactions.return_code.contains('Successfully'), 'source_number'] = transactions.return_code`

Comment: @Erfan yes I did indeed

Comment: Please check the answer which is suggested, this will answer your question. You want to conditionally replace values.

Comment: @Erfan thanks, I tried to refer to it but my problem is that I do not want to replace with a fix value but rather with the value of the second column and I don't know how to do that

Comment: The answer is there, please read carefully. You can solve your problem easily with `np.where` from the `numpy` module. This works as following `np.where(condition, value if condition true, value if condition false)` In your case you can refer to values of columns easily with `transactions.source_number` or `transactions.return_code`.

Comment: @Erfan works like a charm! thank you very much